# alarm manager to trigger at different time intervals

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

Can a single alarm manager trigger at 2 different time intervals like first interval should be 1 minute and second interval should be something like 2 minutes

I was trying with following code but it is not working as i have expected :(

```
{
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 *x, pi); 
}

//Initialized x=1;
//In onReceive what i did was...
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   if(x===1) 
       x=2;
   else
       x=1; 
}
```

Is this wrong ?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a simple way.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Alarm manager is always single - it just add new alarms based on your pending intent.

Comment: I was trying to make wifi auto toggle ,for 1 min it should be ON & next 2 min it should be OFF !!
so are u sayng it wont receive x value ?? @nikis

Answer (score 0):

From the Google developer document

A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call toonReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.

So your x will be always 1. Make the x variable static.

Comment: thanks for the info buddy
Tried with static but it doesnt wrk :( @arul

Comment: Try initializing x in a different class apart from broadcast receiver class